# bash loop comparing date strings

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

Given a start date, I set the date to the end of the month of the previous year, and then try to loop 12m using a bash while loop.

The following loop never exits, and the date eventually skips from the end of the month to the beginning of the next one.

```
 startdate="2014-06-22"
 cod=${startdate:0:7}-01
 echo $cod
 cod=$( date --date "$cod -1 year +1 month -1 day " +"%Y-%m-%d" )
 echo "$cod , $startdate "
 while [ "$cod" < "$startdate" ];  
 do
     echo $cod
     cod=$( date --date "$cod +1 month" +"%Y-%m-%d" )
     echo $cod
 done
```

What I'm expecting is

```
 2013-06-30
 2013-07-31
 2013-08-31
 2013-09-30
 2013-10-31
 2013-11-30
 2013-12-31
 2014-01-31
 2014-02-28
 2014-03-31
 2014-04-30
 2014-05-31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want is the last day of each month, but you are trying to get it by taking the first "last day of the month" and adding one month each time. That doesn't work because you get January 30th and then March 2nd rather than February 28th, because February is weird and "+1 month" is weird :-)

```
$ date -d '2014-01-30'
Thu Jan 30 00:00:00 GMT 2014
$ date -d '2014-01-30 +1 month'
Sun Mar  2 00:00:00 GMT 2014
```

To get the last day of each month you need to repeat the trick you use on the first date - find the first day of the following month and then -1 day from it.

```
#!/bin/bash

startdate="2014-06-22"
cod=${startdate:0:7}-01
cod=$( date --date "$cod -1 year +1 month -1 day " +"%Y-%m-%d" )
for i in $(seq 1 12); do
    echo $cod
    cod=$( date --date "$(date --date "$cod +32 day" +"%Y-%m-01") -1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d" )
done
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ./twelve_months.sh
2013-06-30
2013-07-31
2013-08-31
2013-09-30
2013-10-31
2013-11-30
2013-12-31
2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2014-03-31
2014-04-30
2014-05-31
```

Note that I also changed the loop to a straight `1 .. 12` instead of a while loop with a logic check. The while loop seemed needlessly complicated when you know you always want twelve dates.

Comment: +1 good point, completely ignored the rest of the script after the minute error.

Answer (score 2):

`<` is getting executed by the shell. You need to escape it or use the `[[` keyword for lexicographic comparison.

```
while [ "$cod" \< "$startdate" ];
```

or

```
while [[ "$cod" < "$startdate" ]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can compare date strings, but I am sure you can convert date strings to epoch and compare them as integer

Epoch is time in seconds since `1/1/1970 00:00:00+000`

example:

```
 startdate="2014-06-22"
 epoch_start=$(date -d "$startdate" +%s)

 cod=$startdate
 cod=$( date --date "$cod -1 year +1 month -1 day " +%s )

 while [ "$cod" -lt "$epoch_start" ];  
 do
     date=$(date -d "@${cod}" +%Y-%m-%d)
     date -d "@${cod}" +%Y-%m-%d
     cod=$(date --date "${date} +1 month" +%s)
 done

 date -d "@${cod}" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Output:

```
bash   test4.sh 
2013-07-21
2013-08-21
2013-09-21
2013-10-21
2013-11-21
2013-12-21
2014-01-21
2014-02-21
2014-03-21
2014-04-21
2014-05-21
2014-06-21
2014-07-21
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: You can't compare date strings ... except when they are in a lexicographic format, meaning the highest magnitude part of the date comes first, i.e. `years before months before days`